# Dropsort with a Twist

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

This is my first attempt at a Code Golf question.  If it needs obvious edits, please feel free to make them.

Below is a description of the basic Dropsort algorithm.

> [Dropsort](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/dropsort.html) is run on a list of numbers by examining the numbers in sequence, beginning with the second number in the list. If the number being examined is less than the number before it, drop it from the list. Otherwise, it is in sorted order, so keep it. Then move to the next number.
>
> After a single pass of this algorithm, the list will only contain numbers that are at least as large as the previous number in the list. In other words, the list will be sorted!

For example, given a list of numbers `1,65,40,155,120,122`, the `40,120,122` numbers will be dropped, leaving `1,65,155` in the sorted list.

**Let's implement a new sorting algorithm called DropSortTwist.**

This sort is identical to Dropsort except that a number (including the first number) that would be kept in Dropsort may optionally be dropped instead.  DropSortTwist must return (one of) the longest possible sorted list.

For example, using the same list of numbers as above, DropSortTwist must return either `1,65,120,122` or `1,40,120,122`.  In both cases the `155` number is dropped to achieve a sorted list of length 4, one greater than the Dropsort list.

In this task, you will be given a list of integers as input (STDIN or function argument, you are required to support at least the range of 8-bit signed integers.)  You must return the longest possible increasing subsequence.

You may assume that the list is non-empty.

This is code golf, so the shortest program wins.

**Test Cases**

```
input                    output
1 65 40 155 120 122      1 65 120 122  [or]  1 40 120 122
5 1 2 2 3 4              1 2 2 3 4
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  If I understood this correctly you want the [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)?  While the motivations for the challenge are nice it would be best if you could describe the task without relying on users to follow to other links.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic:  Thank you!  I have tried to clarify the question and reduce the links.

Comment: [Probable dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36566/76162), but it is an older question with a different output format (length of subsequence) and some restrictions on time

Comment: @Joking:  Good find!  I agree that it is a dupe.  Is it preferred that I delete my question, or just wait and let it get marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @James It is preferred if you let it get marked duplicate.

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe. The timing restriction is very significant. I'd expect all serious answers to this question to fail the timing requirements of the older one (my answer sure does).

Comment: Agreed, I do not think this is a dupe of that dupe target since that one restricts the input domain to `[1,999]` and implements a "must execute this (1000 entry test case) in a 'timely manner'" restriction, making competitive answers unlikely to be transferable in either direction.

Comment: I also disagree that it's a dupe. Returning the length of the sequence vs returning the sequence is a bit different problem.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic As per the comments above, this is not a dupe. I have a 6-byte answer that works here that would be invalid for the linked question

Comment: @NickKennedy Fair enough.  I have gone ahead and reopened it.  I had pretty much ignored the time restriction since it was vague enough I figured it wasn't really a restriction, but it seems that that is not how other people see it.  Thanks.

Comment: May we return more than one subsequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒPṢƑƇṪ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opICHOxcdm3is/eHOVf///4821FEwM9VRMDHQUTA0BTIMjUAsI6NYAA)**

#### How?

Pretty much the same approach as [Grimy's 05AB1E entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189601/53748)

```
ŒPṢƑƇṪ - Link: list of integers
ŒP     - power-set (all subsequences, from shortest to longest)
    Ƈ  - filter keep those which are:
   Ƒ   -   invariant when:
  Ṣ    -     sorted
     Ṫ - tail
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
æʒD{Q}éθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJTk1yqA2sPrzy34///aEMdBTNTHQUTAx0FQ1Mgw9AIxDIyigUA)

```
æ           # list of subsequences
 ʒD{Q}      # filter, keep only the sorted subsequences
      é     # sort by length
       θ    # get the last (longest) one
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 bytes

```
à ñÊf_eZñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4CDxymZfZVrx&input=WzEgNjUgNDAgMTU1IDEyMCAxMjJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>89</s> 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda A:A>sorted(A)and max([f(A[:i]+A[i+1:])for i in range(len(A))],key=len)or A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYqxDsIgFEV3v@KNkL5BqHVoUpP3HYQBAyixhQYZ7NcjdTCa3OHec8@6lXuKslY/zWa5WgM00uWZcnGWETfRwmJeTHlGagy6IxU6MWruU4YAIUI28ebY7GKzucaH26Y2eLuprjnEAp4pgXAeEE5HBDG0IuTepNT88HV2jCA/6Zv7@wmU2OMf0ry@AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éÑ<┬Θ╡Lφ0
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82a53cc2e9b54ced30&i=[1+65+40+155+120+122]%0A[5+1+2+2+3+4]&a=1&m=2)

Naive approach: powerset, filter for sorted, sort on length, get tail.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->a{s=a.size;s-=1until r=a.combination(s).find{|e|e==e.sort};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxCsMgFAD3fsUbIxiptukSXn6kZDCpgmC1@MzQJvl2a7oUbjiOS8v0LhZLO@iVUAtyH9NTi3IJ2XlINc3xObmgs4uhISasC491M5tBNIJiynuf9vICK2btfXOXHG4dh@uZg@yqSHWYUiM7/aejc1A/LnUeWfkC)

```ruby
->a{                                    # Anonymous Proc taking array input
    s=a.size;                           # Get array size

        until                           # Loop until the following condition is non-nil:
              r=a.combination(s)        #   Get all subsequences with length s
                    .find{|e|e==e.sort} #   Find a subsequence that is sorted, else nil
    s-=1                                # Reduce s by 1

    r                                   # Implicit return the found subsequence
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 37 bytes

```
Select[Reverse@Subsets@#,OrderedQ,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pzg1JzW5JDootSy1qDjVIbg0qTi1pNhBWce/KCW1KDUlUMcwVu1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoNyrJq@QzVXtaGOgpmpjoKJgY6CoSmQYWgEYhkZ1epwVYO4OgpGYGQMVAMSq@Wq/Q8A)

The elements of `Subsets[ ]` are ordered from shortest to longest, so reversing it puts longer subsets first. Then, select the first one which is ordered.